# different versions of python in one mac, how can I open a specific version among them?

Tags: python

I just started learning python and while I tried to follow several examples, I installed different versions of python in my mac.
I found out there are already python in my mac later, and I did not consider it seriously.

Anyway, I tried to do something with idle, or python 3.5, and it does not have bumpy module.
I then tried to install the module so I opened a terminal and "pip install bumpy:"
it says it already has that in python2.7

Are there ways that I can do pip install thing in terminal into python3.5?

Thanks a lot.

Sincerely,
Jaeho

Comment: `pip3 install` will do.

Comment: are you aware of [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pip for 3.5:

```sh
pip3.5 install bumpy
```